# Trying to turn multiple rows of categorical variables into single row with dummy variable columns

Tags: python, multiple-columns, rows, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a dataset:

```
ID   Action      Converted
567  Email         True
567  Text          True
567  Phone call    True
432  Phone call    False
432  Social Media  False
432  Text          False
```

and i want the final table to look like

```
ID  Email Text PhoneCall SocialMedia Converted
567 1     1    1         0             True
432 0     1    1         1             False
```

this is a small sample. I have 300+ unique actions so manually typing them out is not an option. Basically want to convert these categorical variables in multiple rows into a single row with the actions showing up as dummy variables.

Comment: Using onehotencoder and then getting column names by "get_feature_names" would be a way too. Then grouping by ID and summing.

Answer (score 1):

pd.get_dummies converts categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables. Then groupby will concat the dataframe based on similar IDs and sum will be adding 1 to 0s in the Action columns

```
y = pd.get_dummies(df.Action, prefix='Action')
y['ID']=df.ID
y.groupby(['ID']).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 2 questions, is it possible to have a count instead of it being a dummy? I noticed as i dug deeper that those actions can occur more than once. Secondly this code deletes other columns (or doesnt carry them over). Is there a way to retain other original columns? One of the columns is a target variable.

Comment: For the first one, you can use different aggregate function like count()
And the second problem occurred because you have only action and id feature in y dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Action']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

| ID | Email | Phone call | Social Media | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 567 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thank you both - this worked. What if instead of dummy i wanted the count of occurrences? Example if Phonecall were to be 5 for example

Comment: Also is there a way to retain other columns. Using this code it removes all other columns (in my case it removes the target variable column)

Comment: This code does count the occurences with `size()`. It should also work on your larger dataset. And what is the target variable column? There is none in your sample df.

Comment: Hey! I have updated what the original data set looks like with a target variable. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Is 567 always True,  and 432 always False? If so, it can easily be added, if not, there is no way to represent this column, as the output is grouped by `ID`

Comment: Yes the target variable's value is fixed to the ID, it will not be different. So 567 always true and 432 always False